# Unhide a hidden parameter in HTML using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, attr, hidden-field

I have a hidden parameter in HTML as :

```
<input name ="int" id="time-interval" type="hidden" value="">
```

Now, I want to unhide it and assign a value to it as :

```
 $('#time-interval').show();
    $('input[name="int"]').attr('value',timeintervalmsg);
```

However, this does not works. 
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setup your hidden element using the elements css or `style` and `display`, this is what jQuery changes using `hide()` and `show()`:

```
<input name ="int" id="time-interval" style="display: none" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using "display: none", not a hidden input. Otherwise, you would need to change the type of the input - and, I'm actually not sure how well that works. Also, the jQuery "show" and "hide" method manipulate the "display" value, so using "type='hidden'" wouldn't work anyway.

For your Javascript, you can chain the methods so that you only need one line of code. This way, you don't need to call the jQuery selector twice.

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="time-interval" name="int" style="display: none;">
```

Then:

```
$("#time-interval").show().val(timeintervalmsg);
```